in Django admin page. How can the entry be changed based on a change in the value of a field?
i use django 5 and i have this code
when i choice 'D' the doctor field must active
if i change to 'H' the doctor must deactive and hospital become active and so
class InputMovment(models.Model):
    SOURCE_MOVE = {
        'D':_('doctor'),
        'H':_('hospital'),
        'C':_('company'),        
        'O':_('other'),
    }
    source = models.CharField( max_length=1, choices=SOURCE_MOVE, default='D', verbose_name=_("source"), db_index=True)
    move_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('number'))
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('اdoctor'))
    hospital = models.ForeignKey('Hospital', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('اhospital'))
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('اcompany'))
    persone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('other'))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('description'))


I tried to find a function to change the field, like change_field or something like that but I could not find it
Does anyone have any idea for a solution?
